# my sqllite db is deleted when doing hot restart

Tags: flutter

i don't know how to present my problem , i built a notes app with multiple classes and views so it will be hard to share my code, but the problem is when i perform hot restart the sqllite db is deleted but when i close  the app and open it again the problem does not happen , i know  that hot restart probobly excutes a code that i'm not wanting to excute, but as i mention colsing the app and reopent it again again , so should i just keep it as it is or should i insvesatget more to find the problem

i tried to find a code that drops the database i only have one in the lougout section but it does not seems to excute only when i click on a button